# nginx remove extra trailing slash ate the end of URL

Tags: web-services, http, nginx, https, http-status-code-301

I have this configuration inside `server` block which redirects all `http requests to the https server` with a `301, moved permanently` status.

The problem is that in `Screaming Frog` or `Chrome` I can see that `http://kida.al` is redirected to **https://kida.al//** and then to  `https://kida.al/`.

How can I prevent such a thing?

Thanks!

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name kida.al;

    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri/;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the extra trailing slash from the end of your redirection path:

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Comment: But I want my urls to end with `/`.

Comment: If they already ends with `/`, then you just add another one. Also with your current configuration the `http://kida.al/style.min.css` request is redirected to `http://kida.al/style.min.css/`, which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that. I made the changes. It affected page load also right? Those   redirects?

Comment: Sure. Each redirect adds additional delay.

Comment: If you use HSTS it can save you this redirect and it's more secure (but read carefully the docs before!)